# Add on click event on dynamically created buttons that on click change modal h4 text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have dynamically created buttons and i want to dynamically append on click event on them which changes modal h4 text.
So i have have a declared js object and with
`console.log(dataview[0].subDirs[0]);`

it gives me `postsview/postview001/1.txt` which is what i want.

So i have object and im using .txt files for text in this object i have file path of these .txt files what i want is to add click event to my dynamically created buttons and the first button changes modal h4 text equal to the frist .txt file content

```
  //So this is the function that gets the text of the .txt file and append it to the modal h4

            function appendmodalheader(path){
                    $.ajax({                                 
                    url : path,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (txtcontent) {                               
                    $('#mod-header').text(txtcontent);
                    }
                }); 
            }
   //this is a loop where i loop through all .txt files and for each file
 //I'm appending on click event to the related button
   // buttons id are submit0, submit1, ... 


                for (var i = 0; i < dataview.length; i++){
                    $('#submit' + i).on('click', function(){
                        appendmodalheader(dataview[i].subDirs[0]);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    });
                }
```

The problem is that this script below seems to not work and `modal.('show');` isnt executing because of that

```
appendmodalheader(dataview[i].subDirs[0]);
```

So how to  really create click event on dynamically created buttons that these buttons have different click function

Comment: Can you show what dataview[0].subDirs[0] equals? The URL for that ajax call needs to be something like "/Home/AjaxMethod"

Comment: Never mind I see that you have that above, the issue is the url needs to be just a url so: postsview/postview001 - meaning postview001 is the method you are calling, the parameter of 1.txt needs to be passed as data using the data parameter

Comment: but i have done this different way and it wors i just pass the url the function gets the url text in my case .txt file text and place it in an html element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind event on to the container (which is NOT a dynamically created element) and delegate it to a button.

Something like this may be if I understand your problem correctly!

```
//Lets say all your buttons are inside a container with class 'foo'
//Add a common class for your buttons to which the event will be delegated
//have the 'i' of your example as data-id (or any data attribute of your choice :)) to the button
$('.foo').on('click','.buttonCalss',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');//identifying which button is clicked
    appendmodalheader(dataview[i].subDirs[0]);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
});
```

ADDING data attribute syntax:

```
$("<button />",{text : 'Разгледай', type : 'button', class : 'btn btn-information', id:id}).appendTo(post).data('id',id);
```

Retrieving the id:

```
$(post).on('click','.btn',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    //Do anything with that :)
})
```

Comment: ok but dataview[i] return nothing how to get the last digits of id

Comment: Dont use id as your 'key' identifier. Use data attribute. Eg: instead of <button id="exampleid1"></button>, use <button class="someClassToBeUsedAsSelector" data-id="1"></button>. Now you can have a single event binded to all the buttons of the class by $('.container').on('click','.someClassToBeUsedAsSelector',function(){var id = $(this).data('id') //will give you your id})

Comment: the 'i' I assumed will come from when you are creating the buttons!

Comment: Ok so i click a button and i identify which button is clicked then i need if its  id is for example #submit1 i get the digit '1' and put it inside dataview[]

Comment: btw im using this as function to create the button how to also add data-id

      function addButton(id,i){
       var button = $("<button />",{text : 'Разгледай', type : 'button', class : 'btn btn-information', id:id}).appendTo(post);
       //<button type="button" class="btn btn-information">Разгледай</button>
      }